# Adding refresh icon in JSF panel header

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, font-awesome, jsf-2.2

I'm using JSF/Prime faces for UI. Here I have a `data-table` inside a `Panel`. I need to have a Refresh Icon provided for Font Awesome in Panel's header. On Click of refresh icon data in `data-table` should get refreshed. How can I achieve it?

I tried adding `icon` attribute and also tried using `<i>` tag, but didn't work

```
<p:panel header="Top" styleClass="dynamicleftinnerheader" icon="fa fa-refresh">
    <p:dataTable value="#{controller.dataTable}" var="top" scrollHeight="50">
        <p:column headerText="Item">
            <h:outputText value="#{top.item}"/>
        </p:column>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Try out the [custom actions](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml) example. Please also clean up your [tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging).

Comment: Don't you have to close <p:dataTable.. tag somewhere before you close </p:panel>?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I tried with [Custom Actions](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml) provided by prime faces and it's working.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92505/should-i-flag-answers-which-contain-only-a-link-as-not-an-answer

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:form>
    <p:panel styleClass="dynamicleftinnerheader">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:commandButton icon="fa fa-refresh" update="dataTableId"
                action="#{controller.updateTable()}"></p:commandButton>
        </f:facet>
        <p:dataTable id="dataTableId" value="#{controller.dataTable}"
            var="top" scrollHeight="50">
            <p:column headerText="Item">
                <h:outputText value="#{top.item}"/>
            </p:column>
        </p:dataTable>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```